# Update user collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've got a method which updates a user field. This works but just on client, if I reload the app this field starts from 0 again.

Method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    addPublication: function (publications) {
        check(publications, Number);

        Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {
            $set:{
                publications: publications
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
  Meteor.call('addPublication', Meteor.user().publications + 1);
```

Allow new values:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
    update: function(userId, user) {
        console.log('UPDATE USER');
        return true; 
    }
});
```

Publish:

- Server

> Meteor.publish('users', function() {
>                 return Meteor.users.find({}, {
>                     fields: {
>                         emails: 1,
>                         profile: 1,
>                         username: 1,
>                         publications: 1,
>                     }
>                 });
>         });

- Client

> Meteor.subscribe('users');

Am I missing something here?

Comment: - No errors but 'UPDATE USER' never shows on server

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but is your method defined on server?

Comment: Is not inside of isServer but is in my API folder with the rest of methods and collection. Anyway, I tried to put it inside isServer and has the same result

Comment: I've got a similar method for another collection and works perfectly. It looks like the problem is only with user collection

Comment: Another stupid one: how do you publish your users collection?

Comment: Never pass the userId of the current user to a method... (you've just created a security hole)

Comment: Ok, changed userId in method by this.userId

Answer (score 0):

You should publish your method also, otherwise this method does not make any change in the database

```
Meteor.publish('addPublication');
```

If you do allow update

```
Meteor.users.allow({
    update: function(userId, user) {
        console.log('UPDATE USER');
        return true; 
    }
});
```

There is no need from this method. You can just go on client:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
        $set:{
            publications: publications
        }
    });
```

Comment: The reason to use a method instead a normal update from my controller was becase another user recommended it. I tried with that and even in the client, publications are not updating.
And I published the method (not sure why this one has to be the only one published) and the result is the same, nothing changes.